# Is there a shortcut to close a project in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I frequently have more than one project open and I have been unable to find the shortcut to close a project.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it on your own.

Go to `Preference -> Keymap`, type `Close Project` in search bar and set-up your keyboard shortcut for this action. Works for me in `Intellij Idea 14.1.2`.

[image]

Comment: Thank! For reference I think `cmd` + `shift` + `W` is consistent for close project as the same shortcut without `shift` closes a tab.

Answer (score 16):

For a portable solution, use the menu bar. The shortcut that way would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: This helped when the window for the project I was working on disappeared and wouldn't ever show again. Thanks!

Comment: Much easier to use than manually creating shortcuts each time you work with another computer. Awesome!

Comment: @Lyuboslav  do you know what is the equivalent in WebStorm? I tried `Alt` + `F` + `J` with no luck.